# How can I upgrade NumPy?

Tags: python, opencv, numpy, homebrew, anaconda

When I installed OpenCV using [Homebrew](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homebrew_%28package_management_software%29) (`brew`), I got this problem whenever I run this command to test `python -c "import cv2"`:

```
RuntimeError: module compiled against API version 9 but this version of numpy is 6
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import
```

I tried to upgrade NumPy, but this is confusing:

```
>>> import numpy
>>> print numpy.__version__
1.6.1
```

When I run brew to upgrade NumPy, I got this problem:

```
brew install -u numpy
Warning: numpy-1.9.1 already installed
```

When I uninstalled it:

```
sudo pip install numpy
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): numpy in ./anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

I have followed [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22585235/python-anaconda-how-to-safely-uninstall) and deleted [Anaconda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anaconda_(Python_distribution)) from my mac.

```
pip install numpy
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): numpy in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
```

But nothing have changed. How can I link the NumPy version to OpenCV?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Because we have two NumPy installations in the system. One is installed by Homebrew and the second is installed by pip. So in order to solve the problem, we need to delete one and use the default NumPy install by OpenCV.

Check the path,

```
import numpy
print numpy.__path__
```

and manually delete it using `rm`.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working for Mac OSX El Capitan, because (a) it refuses to delete the numpy's folder which is in `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python`, and (b) this is generally not a good approach,

Comment: @ИванГеоргиев: How else, then?

Comment: Thank you so much, this solved an issue with conflicting versions that I had put far too much time into. Debian python and pip seem to live in `/usr/lib`, `\usr/local/lib` and `~/.local/lib/`.

Answer (score 80):

When you already have an older version of NumPy, use this:

```
pip install numpy --upgrade
```

If it still doesn't work, try:

```
pip install numpy --upgrade --ignore-installed
```

Answer (score 14):

The error you mentioned happens when you have two versions of NumPy on your system. As you mentioned, the version of NumPy you imported is still not upgraded since you tried to upgrade it through pip (it will upgrade the version existing in `'/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages'` ).

However Python still loads the packages from  `'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/numpy'` where the pre-installed packages live.

In order to upgrade that version you have to use `easy_install`. The other way around this problem is using `virtualenv` and setting up a new environment with all the requirements you need.

Comment: `sudo easy_install numpy` searched added the latest numpy path(already existing coz of my `sudo pip install numpy`). Perfect soln.

Comment: Had similar issue. `sudo easy_install numpy` . It removed previous and updated latest. Traceback `Searching for numpy
Best match: numpy 1.11.2
Removing numpy 1.8.2 from easy-install.pth file
Adding numpy 1.11.2 to easy-install.pth file
`

Comment: This worked for me as well (first installing it using pip --ignore-installed, then "linking" it so python finds it using sudo easy_install numpy). The other solutions didn't work.

Comment: sudo easy_install numpy did not work for me, but sudo pip install --ignore-installed numpy did work nicely. Thanks BjornW.

Answer (score 10):

## Update numpy

**For python 2**

```
pip install numpy --upgrade
```

*You would also needed to upgrade your tables as well for updated version of numpy. so,*

```
pip install tables --upgrade
```

**For python 3**

```
pip3 install numpy --upgrade
```

Similarly, the tables for python3 :-

```
pip3 install tables --upgrade
```

## note:

**You need to check which python version are you using. pip for python 2.7+ or pip3 for python 3+**

Answer (score 6):

FYI, when you using or importing TensorFlow, a similar error may occur, like (caused by NumPy):

```
RuntimeError: module compiled against API version 0xa but this version of numpy is 0x9
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 60, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow = swig_import_helper()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow', fp, pathname, description)
ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import


Error importing tensorflow.  Unless you are using bazel,
you should not try to import tensorflow from its source directory;
please exit the tensorflow source tree, and relaunch your python interpreter
from there.
```

I followed Elmira's and Drew's solution, `sudo easy_install numpy`, and it *worked*!

```
sudo easy_install numpy
Searching for numpy
Best match: numpy 1.11.3
Removing numpy 1.8.2 from easy-install.pth file
Adding numpy 1.11.3 to easy-install.pth file

Using /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Processing dependencies for numpy
Finished processing dependencies for numpy
```

After that I could use TensorFlow without error.

Answer (score 3):

I tried doing `sudo pip uninstall numpy` instead, because the `rm` didn't work at first.

Hopefully that helps.

Uninstalling then to install it again.

Answer (score 3):

Because you have multiple versions of NumPy installed.

Try `pip uninstall numpy` and `pip list | grep numpy` several times, until you see no output from `pip list | grep numpy`.

Then `pip install numpy` will get you the newest version of NumPy.

Answer (score 3):

This  works for me:

```
pip install numpy --upgrade
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't encounter any permission errors with

```
pip install -U numpy
```

try:

```
pip install --user -U numpy
```

Comment: I know this is a couple of years old, but awesome ty

Answer (score 1):

After installing pytorch, I got a similar error when I used:

```
import torch
```

Removing NumPy didn't help (I actually renamed NumPy, so I reverted back after it didn't work). The following commands worked for me:

```
sudo pip install numpy --upgrade
sudo easy_install numpy
```

Answer (score 1):

All the same.

```
   sudo easy_install numpy
```

My Traceback

```
Searching for numpy

Best match: numpy 1.13.0

Adding numpy 1.13.0 to easy-install.pth file

Using /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages

Processing dependencies for numpy
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using multiple versions of `Python` (for example `3.8` and `3.9`), then specify explicitly for which one you want to install and update `numpy`:

```
python3.8 -m pip install numpy --upgrade
# or 
python3.9 -m pip install numpy --upgrade
```

Then run your program with the appropriate version of Python.

Answer (score 0):

If you are stuck with a machine where you don't have root access, then it is better to deal with a custom Python installation.

The Anaconda installation worked like a charm:

- *[Installing packages](https://www.scipy.org/install.html)* (SciPy.org)
- *[Anaconda Python/R Distribution - download](https://www.anaconda.com/download/)*

After installation,

> [bash]$  /xxx/devTools/python/anaconda/bin/pip list --format=columns |
>   grep numpy
>
> numpy                              1.13.3                     numpydoc
>   0.7.0

Answer (score 0):

pip install numpy --upgrade

You can try to use the ablove command and use as adminstrator if open CMD.

Comment: this same answer was already given in other answers, among them the top-voted one