# numpy.core.multiarray failed to import

Tags: python, numpy

I used the following command to know the numpy version I am using

```
pip show numpy
```

output shown below

```
---
Name: numpy
Version: 1.8.2
Location: /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Requires:
```

However when I am running matplotlib, I got a error as

```
RuntimeError: module compiled against API version a but this version of numpy is 9
        from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 27, in <module>
        import matplotlib.colorbar
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/colorbar.py", line 32, in <module>
        import matplotlib.artist as martist
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 12, in <module>
        from .transforms import Bbox, IdentityTransform, TransformedBbox, \
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/transforms.py", line 39, in <module>
        from matplotlib._path import (affine_transform, count_bboxes_overlapping_bbox,
```

I tried to upgrade numpy,

```
pip install numpy --upgrade
```

it shows to be installed successfully, but numpy still shows to be 1.8.2 and error continues to exist when running matplotlib.

I thought to uninstall numpy and reinstall it, the system gives the message saying

```
Not uninstalling numpy at /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages, owned by OS
```

how to solve it ? 
any idea about

> RuntimeError: module compiled against API version a but this version
>   of numpy is 9

Comment: you should use **virtualenv** and try this same thing in your environment, is not a good idea to mess up with your system's libraries

Comment: @GermanRosales I don't think virtualenv is good for me, my ubuntu system has too many works and libraries depending on numpy. My numpy is working well at least yesterday. don't know why it doesn't work now. how would people normally upgrade numpy in ubuntu ?

Comment: @user824624 I don't see how **virtualenv** can hurt anybody, but hey if what you want is to rescue your system's **numpy** I would try **apt-get** but only if you know what you are doing there.

Comment: @GermanRosales currently I have matplotlib can't work with numpy, how could I use virtualenv to install numpy and make the current matplotlib work with new numpy in virtualenv

Comment: so did you try **apt-get** to reinstall numpy?

Comment: Having root access: Success with: sudo pip install numpy --upgrade

Answer (score 15):

[How can I upgrade numpy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28517937/how-can-i-upgrade-numpy) might be working for you. IN that case it was a path problem:

```
RuntimeError: module compiled against API version 9 but this version of numpy is 6
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import
```

Solution:

Check the path

```
import numpy
print numpy.__path__
```

and manually delete it using rm

Comment: could you please explain this solution?

Answer (score 6):

I also had the same problem until I came across [this](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/2731) Issue on Pytorch github repository. This command worked perfectly for me:

```
pip install numpy -I
```

It is also mentioned there that `pip install numpy --upgrade` is not working(don't know why). You can check the above mentioned link.

Comment: 3 years later, it worked for me in AWS ec2 virtual machine with python 2.7

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar problem with numpy when running torch. I tried uninstalling numpy and installing it using -U but it didn't work. After some search, I found [this link](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/42441#issuecomment-727222467) and it solved my problem. It says you should change your numpy version.

```
pip uninstall numpy
pip install numpy==1.19.3
```

Comment: I faced this error with Tello Drone "DJITelloPy" and your solution saved the day...Thank you very much.

Comment: uninstalling numpy is basically going to kill my virtual environment this is awful

Answer (score 1):

My problem is solved using the old version of numpy. The solution is to use numpy 1.19.3.

```py
pip install numpy==1.19.3
```

Credit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64730012

Answer (score 0):

The answer is probably simple.
Just add
`import numpy.core.multiarray`
before the 
`import cv2`
statement.
It worked fine for me.

Comment: does not work, also do not really know how this would solve it

Answer (score 0):

Installing the previous version of NumPy, 1.19.3 should fix this.

```
python -m pip install numpy==1.19.3
```