# Problem with CV2 : numpy.core.multiarray failed to import

Tags: python, numpy

Tried to solve it with :

```
pip install -U numpy
```

but it still does not work.

That is what the console shows to me when I try to run the application :

```
    RuntimeError: module compiled against API version 0xa but this version of numpy is 0x9
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Rubio/Desktop/logistic-regression/train.py", line 8, in <module>
    import cv2
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/cv2/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .cv2 import *
ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import
```

Comment: were you able to solve it

Answer (score 1):

Uninstall & Install Numpy

```
conda uninstall numpy

conda install -c conda-forge numpy
```

it works

Answer (score 1):

I had a file named numbers.py in the same folder.
Removing this file solved the issue for me.

Very strange, but worked.

Answer (score 1):

Two solutions. I faced this problem with ai2thor environment.

1. Just add import `numpy.core.multiarray` before the import cv2 statement
2. Update number: `pip install -U --no-cache-dir numpy==1.19.3`

Answer (score 0):

Reinstall OpenCV:

```
conda install -c anaconda opencv (for anaconda users)
```

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that my problem was that I had two versions of numpy installed, I uninstall one of them and it worked normal.

Comment: This is rather than a comment instead of posting as an answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this error with Tello Drone "DJITelloPy" and [this solution from Soroush Karimi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34051737/numpy-core-multiarray-failed-to-import) saved the day.

```
pip uninstall numpy
pip install numpy==1.19.3
```