# how to install numpy for newer python version

Tags: python, numpy

I'm running python 3.5.2 and would like to run

```
>>> import numpy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'numpy'
```

however if I check in a terminal

```
ola@station:~$ pip install numpy
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
ola@station:~$
```

Why do I have so many different pip's?

```
ola@station:~$ pip
pip     pip2    pip2.7  pip3    pip3.4  pip3.5  pip3.6
```

and when I try to use pip3.4 I get

```
ola@station:~$ pip3.5 install numpy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip3.5", line 6, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2991, in <module>
    @_call_aside
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2977, in _call_aside
    f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3004, in _initialize_master_working_set
    working_set = WorkingSet._build_master()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 664, in _build_master
    return cls._build_from_requirements(__requires__)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 677, in _build_from_requirements
    dists = ws.resolve(reqs, Environment())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 856, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req, requirers)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'pip==8.1.2' distribution was not found and is required by the application
```

Comment: Then it is `pip3.5`... For every python version there is a separate package manager.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I upgrade numpy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28517937/how-can-i-upgrade-numpy)

Answer (score 5):

You have one pip for each version of python.
If you want to install numpy for python3.5, you can use :

```
pip3.5 install numpy
```